# PHP bucle y la llamada a funcion AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

a ver si soy capaz de explcarme...

Tengo una consulta MYsql al listado de "categorias". Para editar las categorias, esto no tiene más complicación..
Al lado pongo un interruptor (con un Checkbox, CSS, Label...) para activar y desactivar, la idea es que con AJAX inserte el valor al campo "status"(enum:"0","1") directamente al activar/desactivar.

(nota: es la primera vez que uso una funcion AJAX de este tipo)

Con PHP y un While recojo los datos y con un PRINT monto el listado y pongo el "interruptor" en un formulario para poder recoger los datos...

```
    <form id=\"activa\" method=\"POST\">       
           <main class=\"d-block float-right text-white linia\">
               <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"status\" id=\"pepa".$cont."\" value=\"1\" ".$act."  >
                   <label for=\"pepa".$cont."\"></label>
                    <!-- esto es un botón de prueba -->
                   <button id=\"activat\">eepa</button> 
           </main>
            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"categoria_id\" id=\"categoria_id\" value=\"".$row['id']."\">
</form>
```

Y aqui la función

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
         //$('#pepa').change(function(){//esto funciona en forma simple, lo anulo
        $('#activat').click(function(){
      
            var datos=$('#activa').serialize();
            alert(datos);//hago Chivato para ver si funciona
            return false;//lo paro aquí
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"category-active.php",
                data:datos,
                success:function(r){
                    if(r==1){
                        alert("YES");
                    }else{
                        alert("UPS");
                    }
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Problemas que me surgen, tuve que añadir un contador "$cont" para poder cambiar el id de cada interruptor, porqué sino actuán como uno solo al chekearlo, por lo que en la funcion no puedo recoger el "id", y aunque recoja otro dato, tambien deberia cambiar el nombre a cada formulario que imprima.

En resumen, que creo que deberia llamar a la funcion desde dentro el bucle para que sea los datos del lugar donde esté.. (no se si me explico bien) y aqui es donde estoy PERDIDO.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

No entendi muy bien cual es el problema, pero lo primero que veo en el codigo es que tu id en el form es "activa" y tu id en el jQuery es "activat"

```
<form id=\"activa\" method
```

```
$('#activat').click(function(){
```

A la mejor por eso NO ESTA ejecuando la funcion al "click", empieza por checar si corrigiendo el nombre se soluciona "tu problema".

Comment: "Activat" es el id Button de prueba, funciona bien. El id del Form "activa" lo recoge enla $var datos... pero gracias.
Elproblema es que si esto esta en un bucle y tengo 10 categorias, me genera10 forms conel mismo id, y la función va enviar los datos del ultimo, no del que desactive... y por otro lado el boton también estara 10 veces. Basicamente tengo que conseguir identificarlo todo....